# Two 'h2' Headers in HTML5

Tags: html

My class was asked to use HTML5, not CSS, to create this web page.

Question: I have two h2s, I read somewhere that this is legal and two sets of "unordered lists", but they are not lining up. I mean lining right under each other: example
Confusion
 aaa
 bbb
 ccc
Calm
 abc
 bca
 bac
They are lining up cantilever (?). The Calm header & its lists are more to the right. I've researched several sites and have not come up with why this is happening. I appreciate your help and insight.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Serenity</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body 
        {
                background-image:url("images/bg-ocean-body.jpg");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
    </style>
        <h1 span style="text-align:center; color:green;">Achieving Calm Amid<span style="color:black"> Confusion</h1>
         <h2>Confusion</h2>
         <ul>
            <li>Government Shutdown</li>
            <li>"do nothing" congress</li>
            <li>bridgegate, sandygate</li>
            <li>Putin, Sochi</li>

        <h2 span style="color: green; text-align:left;">Calm</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>wipe away stress</li>
            <li>gain mental/emotional balance</li>
            <li>anxiety decreases</li>
            <li>develop perspective</li> 
        </ul>

</head> 

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot close first <ul> tag by adding </ul> and you should use <span> instead of <h2 span ... >

Comment: `"My class was asked to use HTML5, not CSS, to create this web page."` - Your class seems to be receiving some misinformation about what HTML (5 or otherwise) and CSS actually *are*.

Comment: Thank you Виктор Перов and all who answered. I did not  notice the missing </ul> tag.  

ElendilTheTall your explanation was "spot on". Thank you

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (no `<body>` tags and everything in `head`), and you DO use CSS (`style="..."` and `<style></style>`)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `<span>` tags in the wrong place. `<span>` is a separate tag, not an attribute of `<h2>`.

You are nearly using `<span>` correctly around **confusion**, for example, but you are not closing it with `</span>`.

I believe you're looking to do something like:

`<h1><span style="text-align:center; color:green;">Achieving Calm Amid</span><span style="color:black"> Confusion</span></h1>`

Also, you need to close your first `<ul>` tag with `</ul>`.